# Css Hack Issue In Safari

Tags: css, safari

I tried this below code but still it is working on both Safari & Chrome.

Please let me know a hack **only** for Safari not Chrome

```
.contactDiv img:not(:root:root) { 
    margin-top:-75px;
}  

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .contactDiv img{
         margin-top:-75px;
    }
}
```

Both are working on Chrome as well as Safari but I want that only on Safari.

Comment: Sounds like a somewhat drastic "hack". Why do you need this? Can't you make the same code work on both?

Comment: No actually it is differ i can;t understand why it is happen but now i have no solution I have to apply hacks so please if u have any hack which run onllly on safari please let me know

Comment: is there a css hack for safari only NOT chrome?  in that link all codes are running on both not only in safari. I want only safari hack

Comment: You might not need to hack anything. You might just need to change your approach to how you are coding it. Can you create a working example and explain what you are trying to do with the code

Comment: It is a custom layout without bootstrap and I am putting up that image with minus margin but px differ on differ browser specially safari

Comment: "Without bootstrap"? You have to specifically mention that nowadays? Has it really come to this? Good grief...

Comment: I' ll manage thanks for reply

Comment: are you using any sort of server side language?  No

Answer (score 0):

Try Following type of rule:

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {}
```

Or you can check media hack from [Browser Hack](http://browserhacks.com/) also

Comment: It's wrong. any other?

Comment: try Rule from this link :https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/css-hacks-for-safari-6-1-7-and-8-not-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

This hack is going to work only on Safari:

```
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .contactDiv img {   margin-top:-75px; }
```